# to be due something - in the meaning of expecting, owing

Tags: prepositions, adjectives

I am desperately trying to understand this concept.

Lets use this sentence:

> The world is due ‘a major cyber attack causing widespread harm’ before
>   2025, say experts”.

Dictionaries do not mention usage of due without a preposition in this meaning. When talking about expectations, Oxford mentiones "due for" or "due to do sth".

In the entry "Owed", it does mention "due something" with a note [not before noun]. And the example says "I'm still due 15 days' leave."

I cannot find more about the usage "to be due sth" in terms of to expect something. Could you help me understand which dictionary (Oxfortd online e.g.) is that and how that applies?
THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this Wiktionary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_adjectives_taking_noun_phrase_complements),

> A small number of English adjectives take noun phrase [complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(linguistics)). CGEL lists only four: **due**, like, unlike, and worth. Underweight and probably overweight are also in this class. There may be others.

So, "a major cyber attack.." is a complement that the adjective **due** takes in your sentence.

The meaning, again according to Wiktionary's entry on **[due](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/due#Adjective)**, is "owed or owing". Wiktionary provides the following example:

> He is **due** [four weeks of back pay]. (a [noun phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) complement in square brackets)

The note "*not before a noun*" means that **due** in this sense cannot be used as an **[attributive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective#Types_of_use)** adjective, but only as a predicative or postpositive adjective. An attributive adjective is used like this:

> The threat of cyber attack should be given **due** attention. (the adjective *due* stands *before a noun*, and this noun is *attention*)

In your example sentence, **due** is used predicatively. It would be hard to use it attributively in this sense anyway, since we need to attach the complement to it somehow:

> The experts say that our world is a **due** [a major cyber attack causing widespread harm before 2025] world.

(I used **due** before the noun **world**, that is, *attributively*, and inserted the complement between the adjective and the noun. The result looks outlandish).

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. But why does the dictionary mentiones "not before noun"?

Comment: @SillkySand - I've expanded my answer.

Comment: "not before noun"? How about "due date"? :p

Comment: @bobbee - I wrote **in this sense**. An adjective can have numerous senses. *[Due](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/due?searchDictCode=all)* can be used both predicatively or attributively. In "due date", the adjective is used attributively, and its meaning differs a bit from the *predicative use* in "Bobbee is due [a good foray into Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective#Types_of_use)" (0:

Comment: Just joking my friend :^)

Comment: @bobbee - I know, me too, amigo. (0: A good question, it made me expand the answer! The authors of the dictionary wanted to spare the reader from getting into the linguistic jargon, but ended up befuddling him, since **due** indeed takes a **noun phrase** complement.

Comment: Addendum: CGEL discusses the four adjectives on page 546.